# Confusion about changed handling of TYPO3 variable "$_EXTKEY"

Tags: typo3

I am confused by this:
in newer versions of TYPO3 (>8) the variable "$_EXTKEY" is not set automatically anymore, so I learned, for example here:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/exceptions/main/en-us/Exceptions/1478105826.html?highlight=_extkey#using-extkey-in-configuration-files-in-typo3-v9-and-above

In one of my projects (v11) this causes problems with extensions, in another one (v12) not.

The problems are related to the usage in 'ext_emconf.php' files inside the extensions .

If I replace

```
$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = array ()
```

with

```
$EM_CONF['extensionname'] = array ()
```

it works in my v11-project.

BUT a lot of well known extensions still use $_EXTKEY at this place, and I can't find out why this works.

Addition: I really did some research on this, sorry if it still doesn't meet the high standards here.

Comment: In ext_emconf.php using $_EXTKEY is still valid (and should be kept). In all other places this variable is not defined anymore.

Comment: Thanks, so there must be another reason why it's not working in one case.

Answer (score 3):

It can be a little bit confusing, yes...

In "TYPO3 explained" there is a section "[Rules and best practices](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/BestPractises/ConfigurationFiles.html#rules-and-best-practices)" telling some details:

- You **must** use the extension name (for example, "tt_address") instead
  of `$_EXTKEY` within the two configuration files [`ext_localconf.php` & `ext_tables.php`] as this variable is no
  longer loaded automatically.
- However, due to limitations in the TYPO3 Extension Repository, the
  $_EXTKEY option **must** be kept within an extension's `ext_emconf.php`
  file.

As Chris already wrote, `$_EXTKEY` should still work within `ext_emconf.php`.

Maybe, there is different behavior and handling in the versions, when `extension-key` is set in an extensions `composer.json`.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at composer.